# Connecting SQL 2005 to Oracle 10g

Tags: sql-server-2005, oracle10g

Environment:
 - Oracle 10g database over a windows 32bit 2003 server
 - SQL 2005 database over a windows 32 bit 2003 server.

I am trying to connect the above databases through heterogeneous services. I have updated the following files: TNSNames.ora, Listener.ora and hs.ora. When performing a test connection from SQL developer, I get the following error - ORA 28500 - indicating that the login for SA user is incorrect.

I also tried using another authenticated user that has rights to the database.

I can successfully connect with SQL 2000.

Has anyone experienced such a problem before?

Answer (score 0):

We have an Oracle 10g database that is connected to a SQL Server 2005 instance (similar set up - 32bit on Windows 2003).  We are using the Oracle 10g Transparent Gateway for SQL Server without issue.

Unfortunately I can't speak to Heterogeneous services.  But if you can make the change in your environment, you may want to look into Gateways, I believe it's a free download on OTN.

Documentation: http://download.oracle.com/docs/cd/B19306_01/gateways.102/b14270/toc.htm

Comment: Just because you can download it for free doesn't mean you can use it for free. The MS SQL Server Transparent Gateway from Oracle is quite expensive. http://www.oracle.com/us/corporate/pricing/technology-price-list-070617.pdf